# Specific a href crawling by beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I am trying to learn beautifulsoup.

In the website, it has same a href with different results.

For example, the results of my code is:

0001545654

6798

HI

0001459640

TX

0001269765

CA

0001456527

CA

0001001379

GA

I would like to bring only for numbers

URL for numbers = a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001545654&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0">0001545654

URL for areas = a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&State=HI&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0">HI

I would like to bring only for CIK!

Is there any way to bring only for CIK (0001545654)?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=a&owner=exclude&action=getcompany'
page = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser')

CIK = page.find('table', 'tableFile2').find_all('a')

#print(CIK)
for i in CIK:
    print(i.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be to filter your results so that only valid integers are in it:

```
CIK = [i for i in CIK if str(i.get_text()).isnumeric()]
```

Alternatively, you could refine your BeautifulSoup parsing to only get the first item of each row:

```
CIK = [e.find_all('a')[0] for e in page.find('table', 'tableFile2').find_all('tr')]
```